# QPolygon containPoints does not get expected results

Tags: qt

I am currently working with QT. I am new with it but, the thing I am trying to do is that I draw a line on my window and make a polygon around here so when I click with mouse on the line I would know to locate her. So I am trying to use a `containsPoints()` method of polygon but it doesn´t with any of the parameter either OddEvenFill or WindingFill.

So here is some code where I am creating the polygon :

```
 QPoint topLeft(mStartPoint.x() - 2, mStartPoint.y() - 5);
QPoint topRight(mStartPoint.x() - 2, mStartPoint.y() + 5);
QPoint bottomRight(endPoint.x() + 2, endPoint.y() - 5);
QPoint bottomLeft(endPoint.x() + 2, endPoint.y() + 5);

QVector<QPoint> polygPoints{ topLeft,bottomLeft,topRight,bottomRight};

QPolygon area(polygPoints);
```

and here is the code where I am trying to find if I hit the line or not :

```
for (int i = 0; i < edges->size(); i++) {

   if((*edges)[i]->getArea().containsPoint(posEdge,Qt::WindingFill)){
       index = i;
       break;
    }
}
```

So for example I have a polygon with the points with theese values of coordinates :

```
topLeft - x = 51, y = 49
topRight - x = 124, y = 69
bottomLeft - x = 51, y = 59
bottomRight - x = 124,y = 54
```

and the position of point where I clicked is : x = 80, y = 56
and the

```
containPoints()
```

method still getting false as the point isn´t inside of the polygon.
Do  you have any idea what am I doing wrong ? I would be really thankfull for every help.

Comment: Draw the polygon and you'll instantly see where the problem is. You're trying to solve a geometric problem - it's best if you see it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the points for the polygon - graphically - like this:

```
| ⁄|
|⁄ |
```

try to define the points like you would do drawing a rectangle:

```
|  |
|__|
```

This is `QVector<QPoint> polygPoints{topLeft, bottomLeft, bottomRight, topRight};`. In addition you can repeat the starting point `topLeft`. Defining the polygon this way, it's a rectangle and not two triangulars and the contains function should behave like you expect.

Comment: what do you mean by repeating that start point ? How exactly should my polygPoints looks like ? You meant something like this ? QVector<QPoint> polygPoints{ topLeft, bottomLeft, bottomRight, topLeft };

Comment: Okey so I figured it out, it works already.. Thank you very much for the hint :)